# Processing zip files using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Data Lake
I am looking for information on how to process .zip file which holds a single.
Not sure if I can directly process a contents inside a zip file into Azure Database without unzipping the contents into separate folder.

Another question is the text file is having variable number of column counts in pipe delimiter,as single text file is holding data from multiple tables. Not sure what are the possible ways to process this variable column count text file.

Comment: Hi @VSU, may I know why you never accept others answer? It takes time to give the workarounds or suggestions for you. People will glad to assist you if you can try to accept their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory supports read the file/data in the .zip file, we can set the Compression type for the .zip file and we don't need unzipping the contents into separate folder. See the example bellow:
[image]

For you another question, if the text file has variable number of column counts in pipe delimiter. Data Factory can't do well with this kind of file, it will always consider the first row as the schema according the column delimiter number. Just for now, there isn't a good way to process it.

HTH.